# Android app indexing example

Tags: android, android-app-indexing

I want to implement app indexing in my app.

I have already done [this.](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish#add-app-indexing-api-calls) But I am not sure if it is enough for App Indexing.

Can any body able to give any example or can explain this thing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement App Indexing in your app, you need to follow all the steps in [App Indexing Guide](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app).

Cheers,

MB